# How to configure routes for an ASP.NET MVC web application hosted inside an ASP.NET WebForms web application in Azure App Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, webforms

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application hosted inside an ASP.NET WebForms application on Azure App Service. I have two problems:

1. I can't define the MVC application's connection string with the same name as that of WebForms application. It shows the same connection string name exception. I don't have much problem with this but if anyone could please tell me the reason then I can avoid any such conflicts in the future?
2. This one is the major problem. All of my routes are added to the WebForms application's host instead of the WebForms application's host + the folder of MVC web application.

I tried changing the default route in `RouteConfig.cs` like this:

```
MVCAPP/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

But it's not working and showing access denied error. Although, opening the view directly from the browser address bar is working correctly.

Comment: If possible, could you please share a code demo or detailed steps to setup this environment?

Comment: @IvanYang I created a virtual application inside Azure app service, that was already hosting WebForms application, and hosted my MVC web application there. But I am facing the above-mentioned issues.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-migrate-publish-web-app-to-cloud-service

Comment: I dont have full knowledge about multiple apps but, i can recommend you alternate routing with Attributes on your controller. [Route("MVCAPP/Home")] place it in your Controller classes upside of class name. Or [Route("routetemplatename")]